# Understanding Apache Tomcat Connection Pooling

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

I am trying to implement Apache Tomcat's built-in JDBC connection pool. But I am confused with many things.

There are 2 methods mentioned in official page to initialize connection pool. 
One using JNDI lookup and another by java `PoolProperty` class.

For JNDI lookup, we have to add entry to `context.xml`or `server.xml` and initilize it in the java code. This require database connection details to be hardcoded.

For pool properties, we have to set various connection attributes in `PoolProperty` class using the datasource object. Does it require instantiating factory? (`org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory`)

Whenever a try using pool properties, I am getting the error:

> SEVERE: Unable to create initial connections of pool.
>   java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in call  at
>   oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)

I checked and confirmed all properties are correct. This error goes once I use the xml method. Can someone help me the correct way to configure pooling without xml?

This standalone java code gives me error:
     PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();

```
     String dburl="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname) (PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=shostname2)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=Service)))";

     p.setUrl(dburl);
    p.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    p.setUsername(username);
    p.setPassword(pwd);
    p.setJmxEnabled(true);
    p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
    p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1 from dual");
    p.setTestOnReturn(false);
    p.setValidationInterval(30000);
    p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
    p.setMaxActive(100);
    p.setInitialSize(10);
    p.setMaxWait(10000);
    p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(600);
    p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
    p.setMinIdle(10);
    p.setLogAbandoned(true);

    p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
    p.setJdbcInterceptors(
            "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;"
            + "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;"
            + "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer");

    p.setLogValidationErrors(true);   datasource = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource(  );
    datasource.setPoolProperties(p);
```

When I add A global Resource to Server.xml as below,it is working.

> Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be
>   updated and saved"
>   factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
>   name="jdbc/database"  type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

Please Help me to understand, what's the correct way of implementation.

Comment: Please include the code that doesn't work for you and the XML that does work.

Comment: Done. I copied same properties present in Tomcat page. I am confused with the some details.It says "To configure the pool in a stand alone project using bean instantiation, the bean to instantiate is org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" . In this case do we have to initialize JNDI factory ?

Comment: 5 years later I'm struggling with same problem...Have you found solution? @Shebang_John